# Docker invalid tag value

Tags: linux, macos, docker, repository, owncloud

I'm trying to build the OwnCloud desktop client, for which [the Owncloud docs](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.1/building.html#windows-installer-build-cross-compile) explain that docker should be used:

```
Assuming you are in the root of the ownCloud Client’s source tree, you
can build an image from this Dockerfile like this:

cd admin/win32/docker
docker build . -t ownCloud-client-win32:<version>
```

I get an error with this exact command, so following [the docker build docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) I moved the dot to the end. But then I get the following error:

```
$ docker build -t ownCloud-client-win32:2.1 .
invalid value "ownCloud-client-win32:2.1" for flag -t: Error parsing reference: "ownCloud-client-win32:2.1" is not a valid repository/tag
See 'docker build --help'.
```

Why is `ownCloud-client-win32:2.1` not a valid tag name?

I then just tried running  `docker build .`, which runs successfully, but then I end up with an untagged image.

Does anybody have any idea how I can solve this?

ps. I don't know if it's important, but the relevant [Dockerfile is here](https://github.com/owncloud/client/blob/master/admin/win/docker/Dockerfile).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No uppercase. Try: `owncloud-client-win32:2.1`